# Change zone name for MAAS region/cluster controller

Tags: dns, maas

How safe would it be to change the zone name for the MAAS Region/Cluster controller with nodes already deployed and registered in MAAS DNS?

Currently mine is set to default maas and I would like to change to maas1 (to refer to Cluster 1 as I have other clusters now Cluster 2, 3, etc.).

Many thanks in advance.